# Load polymer element inside bootbox

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to create a map inside a bootbox dialog. Here is the code.

```
bootBox.dialog({ title:"test", message = "<div><google-map latitude='37.77493' longitude='-122.41942'></google-map></div>" });
```

It creates the dialog, creates the maps box with Google logo at bottom but do not load the map. It remains gray.

I found that if I open or close Chrome Developer Tools after the dialog has displayed the map is rendered.

Any suggestion?

Edit after comments:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/bootbox/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="google-map/google-map.html">

    <button onclick="ft()">Open Map</button>

    <script>
        var ft = function(){
            bootbox.dialog({title:'test', message: '<google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942"></google-map>'});    
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the height of `google-map` for it to appear:

```
<style>
  google-map {
    height: 600px;
  }
</style>
<script>
  bootbox.alert({title:'test', message: '<google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942"></google-map>'})
</script>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="google-map/google-map.html">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    google-map {
      height: 600px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    bootbox.alert({
      title: 'test',
      message: '<div><google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942"></google-map></div>'
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JKXZOb?editors=1000)</sup>

Comment: I already set it throught class and style. Did you try? Did it work?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, as can be seen in the demo on Chrome 51 on OS X El Capitan? Do you have a codepen/jsbin/plunker that demonstrates your symptoms?

Comment: I just found the problem. I had another map element in the same page. One was in the bottom and the other inside bootbox. I had to remove the first one. Thanks

Comment: Now I'm facing the same problem but in a different form. The first time that I open the dialog, the map is displayed correctly, but if I don't reload the page, it is not displayed anymore, just like in the original problem. And yes, if I open the dialog and open the Chrome Developer Tools when it is closed, the map is rendered. Why is that?

Comment: Please provide some code context (or a demo on codepen/plunker/etc) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edited the question with an example. The first time you click the button it works, then it will not work anymore.